# How do I avoid title and axis labels being cut off in PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I'm having some difficulty getting the PDF version of my plot to show the title and axis labels. They show up fine in the RStudio plot window, but get cut off in the PDF. I've tried a few things, including different margin settings, the pdf() function with dev.off() but keep getting the same result no matter what I try. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)

#Plot
par(mar=c(6, 6, 6, 2))
ggplot(data = paymentsNY, aes(x = Average.Covered.Charges/1000, y = 
Average.Total.Payments/1000, alpha = 0.25))+ 
geom_point()+
xlab("Mean covered charges ($'000s)")+
ylab("Mean total payments ($'000s)")+
ggtitle("Mean covered charges and mean total payments - NY")+
theme(title = element_text((size = 16)))+
theme(legend.position = "none")+
geom_smooth(method = "lm")

#Write plot as PDF
ggsave("payments_NY.pdf")
```

Thanks

Comment: What I always do is using the plot-viewer pane in Rstudio. There you can manage the size of your plot with the window, and then export -> save as pdf. The size of the saved plot will be the same as this of the viewer pane.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't solve the problem. If I export via the "export" button on the plot viewer window the same thing happens: while the title and labels show up correctly in the viewer window, they do not appear in the PDF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 plot area margins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836843/ggplot2-plot-area-margins)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [similar question](https://github.com/duttashi/visualize/issues/18) some time ago. I provide that answer here.

First, you have to determine the available fonts with the command `windowsFonts()` (*execute this command in RStudio*). The current fonts in my graphing device are;

```
> windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"
```

Thereafter, you can import the extrafont library and the `loadfonts(device = "win")`. I also recommend to execute these commands in the R console and not in RStudio. I suggest this because when you are importing the fonts using font_import() in RStudio, it may not show the `y/n` prompt.

Next, I provide a minimum reproducible example;

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(extrafont)
 # tell where ghostscript is located. This is required for saving the font in pdf
 Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.21\\bin\\gswin64c.exe") # I have installed 64-bit version of GhostScript. This is why I've used gswin64c.exe. If you have installed 32-bit version of GhostScript, use gswin32c.exe. Failure to specify the correct installed GhostScript will yield error message, "GhostScript not found"
 # create a plot object
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
geom_point()+
ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars")+
xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
theme_bw()+
theme(text=element_text(family="ArialMT", size=14))
# show the plot
print(p)

# save the plot as pdf  
ggsave("figures//ggplot_arialmt.pdf", p, width=20, height=20, 
   device = "pdf", units = "cm")
```

Its only the `ArialMT` font that seems to work with ggsave(). See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638529/extrafont-and-ggsave-characters-end-up-on-top-of-another). Using any other font for saving to pdf, renders the figure with characters on top of another. This is also an [open issue](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/34) for ggsave and has not been solved since 2013.